# Is there a site which has a good collection of recumbent bikes, still for sale new, to compare?

Tags: recumbent, resource

I am ready for a new recumbent bike and I know what I want, I also know that I will not be able to get all features in one bike as they are contradictory.

Searching internet shows me a lot of sites with one or a few bikes each or with bikes for sale but not much detail.
On top of that many of the bikes you see described online have been out of sale for years and are very unlikely to be available second hand.

I am based in the Netherlands but with the market as international as it is these days any site with a good collection will be welcome.
Bikes still new in the shops and/or those which have been new in the shops the last 5 years. Sites that collect all that has ever been on sale are less useful.

As I will have to drop some of my 'want have' requirements, I do not look for any particular selection of recumbent bikes.

PS, I am NOT looking for where to buy the recumbent when I have decided on it, I want to weed out a lot of bikes before trying to get to see them because they will not fit my body length or seat height requirements.
I have at least three dedicated recumbent stores within an hour driving distance and at least one local bike store which will order and maintain 'bents but does not usually store them.

I have been riding a recumbent bike for the last 5 years and a recumbent trike for the 5 years before that.
I have been with one or the other to each of the 10 bike shops I feel are near enough to use for common servicing and non of them was selling or even interested in talking about the option of selling this kind of bikes new in the future.
The one bike shop with some recumbents is far enough away that I consider them with the recumbent specialist I will go to when buying but not for day to day service.
(If not cycling, I will be walking the bike to the shop, no use of a car)

Comment: I sympathise  - recumbents are too expensive to risk buying the wrong one.  Can you search out if there's a recumbent event in your area coming up?  There are likely to be sellers with stalls and offering test rides at such an event.

Comment: There is such an event coming up in June, Amsterdam, but I hope to have a bit better view on what I want before then. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: You have 6 months to research then, and much of that in your winter.  Try test rides on any ebay ones in your region, and try to connect with other riders.

Comment: There are certainly local bike shops in NL which carry a significant number of recumbents. I don't understand if you aren't aware of the existence of the shops, or aren't aware of the details of the bikes? In the latter case the manufacturer's website is a much better bet.

Comment: My 'problem' is that I want to compare bikes on paper or internet before traveling out to shops or other owners who might have the bikes. Having hat a 'bent for a few years and having tried the one my friend owns, I know several things I do NOT want in a bike.

Comment: Turned out the event did not have the option to compare bikes. And I fell for one before it even started, on the picture and description of the one. No weighted comparison at all.

Comment: Turns out that in my nation of 4 million, there is exactly one bike shop that specialises in recumbents, and its 600 km away on the other island.    Recumbents aren't cheap which limits their attraction.

Comment: @Criggie, that is a good reason to travel to a country with more options. (But expensive in not always true. I bought a Batavus Relaxx for €200 and now, after 5 years of daily use, will let it go for less. (In need of work.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not a site available (that I am aware of) that does such a thing.  Bicycle Blue Book might be close, but they don't give you the ability to filter by bicycle type.  Somewhat unrelated, I submitted a suggestion to them that they add that feature to their site.

What's available is often not as important as what's available at your LBS.  I suggest anyone new/getting into cycling pick an LBS and start developing a relationship with them by purchasing a bike/trike/bent from them.  A local shop should be able to help you select a bent that meets your requirements, get it fitted and help you keep it maintained after purchase.

Comment: No local bike shop which has recumbents nor do they want to add them but they are willing to service my 'bent. There are three or four recumbent specialists near enough to use but too far to have my bike in service there. +1 for the points you do bring up.